# What material is good for Atiyah-Singer index theorem

Tags: education

I want to ask what materials or books can I use to learn the proof of Atiyah-Singer index theorem? I hope such material contains enough preliminaries and background instead of proving the theorem directly.

Comment: See [Roadmap to study Atiyah-Singer index theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/295050)